# C++ concurrent functions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to stop randomFunction() when i == 5 in the main function. I do know that the current code for randomFunction() will only stop if counter equals 1000 and counter++ gets run 1000 times.

```
class A{
counter = 0;
public:

    void randomFunction()
    {
        while(counter != 1000)
        {
            counter++;
            cout << counter << endl;
        }
        cout << "Task Complete!" << endl;
    }
    

    void stopFunction()
    {
        counter = 1000;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A o;
    o.randomFunction();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            o.stopFunction();
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to run stopFunction() while randomFunction is running?
I'm looking for:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Task Complete!
```

And not:

```
1
...
1000
Task Complete!
```

I'm thinking the solution has to do with library thread and future or mutex, but I do not know where to start.

Comment: What is the point of iterating `i`? I don't understand what significance the loop in `main` has in relation to the loop in `randomFunction`

Comment: Not that it matters much outside of completeness, but you're missing a type here: `counter = 0;`

Comment: You do want an extra thread, whole bunch of different ways to get that, and you definitely want to protect `counter` (I'd start with `std::atomic<int>`), but you'll have to start messing with condition variables and their ilk to get 1,2,3,4,5, complete because once threads start running, who knows where `randomFunction`'s  thread will be when `main`'s  thread hits five. It's possible `randomFunction` steams all the way to 1000 or doesn't even get to start before `main` reaches 5.

Comment: Where to start... Something simpler so you can learn how threads interact in a more controlled manner.